# laravel intertia route params in vue component

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, vue-router, inertiajs

my App is a laravel/intertia/Jetstream/ServerSideRendering Vue3 one page app so everything routes within one vue container over vue router.
let's assume

> localhost/portfolio/1

is my route

When called from within a vue component, everything's fine, meaning the vue component gets the id from the route and searches the corresponding portfolio.
But once a user refreshes the page, he gets a 404 error. which makes sense as until now the route was not defined as laravel route (only a vue3 route).
So I defined the laravel route

```
Route::get('/portfolio/{portfolioId}', function (string $portfolioId) {
    return Inertia::render('Portfolio',['portfolioId'=>$portfolioId]);
})->name('portfolio_id');
```

and the vue component is duplicated (once as component and once as page) and everything should be peachy right?

```
    import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
    import { isProxy, toRaw } from 'vue';
    const router = useRoute();
    console.log("Portfolio route:");
    console.log(router);           // see screenshot
    let rawObject = undefined;
    if(isProxy(router)){ //this If() block is not really necessary
        rawObject = toRaw(router);
        console.log(rawObject);     // 2nd screenshot but now an object
    }

    console.log(rawObject.params);           // empty
    console.log(rawObject.params.portfolioId);      // undefined
```

Well no... (white page, portfolioId Param is undefined).
So I digged

`router.params` or `rawObject.params` `params are undefined`
And I began to hit a wall, beacuse apparently the params are in the route.
[image: console log of router]
but I am not able to extract them. even after seeing that router is a proxy object and transforming it to raw I still can't get the params

[image]

What still gets me, and I really don't understand is why is rawObject.params and router.params empty in vue3 setup even though the proxy evidently has the params???
How do I access the params correctly? I' really hitting a wall